# What makes my page look like this?

Tags: html, css

I spent a hour to find the problem but I still can't find it.
When I zoom in and out in my browser, some elements are moving and some get bigger. For me, the element that is moving, is in his meant position at 67% zoom.

```css
#structure {
 background-color: blue;
 height: 640px;
 width: 1136px;
}

/* Starting the left side menu */
#select {
 background-image: url('http://image.prntscr.com/image/876c2fde408443e0969559dfb4130848.png');
 height: 640px;
 width: 100px;
 border-right: 4px solid rgba(69, 39, 28, 0.9);
 float: left;
}

.menu {
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 34px;
}

.menu img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

#menu1 img, #menu7 img {
 height: 120%;
 width: 100%;
}

#menu1 {
 height: 120px;
 width: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 margin-left: 37px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#menu1 img {
 margin-top: 7px;
 height: 95px;
 width: 28px;
}

#menu7 {
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 margin-top: 85px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
/* Closing the left side menu */


/* Starting slideshow Images */

#slideImg img {
 position: relative;
 height: 640px;
 width: 683px;
 float: left;
}
/* Closing slideshow Images */


/* Starting the quests side */
#quests {
 background-image: url('http://image.prntscr.com/image/46c0de9e96474d5686b175d7cc343516.png');
 height: 640px;
 width: 350px;
 float: left;
}

#seasonLevel {
 height: 62px;
 width: 62px;
 z-index: 60px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 top: 8px;
 left: 10px;
}

#seasonLevel div {
 position: relative;
 top: 4px;
 border: 3px solid white;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 60px;
 width: 60px;
}

#seasonLevel div div {
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 margin: auto;
}

#seasonLevel div div p {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 position: relative;
 bottom: 22px;
}

#seasonDesc {
 width: 220px;
 height: 65px;
 position: relative;
 left: 23px;
 top: 12px;
 float: left;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

#seasonDesc p:first-child {
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 30px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 600;
}

#seasonDesc p:last-child {
 font-size: 23px;
 font-weight: 600;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25px;
 color: #DEDEDE;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

#sunCont {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 z-index: 50px;
 height: 47px;
 width: 314px;
 position: relative;
 right: 8px;
 top: 33px;
 z-index: 30px;
 float: right;
}

.sun {
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.4;
 width: 28px;
 height: 28px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-left: 0.01px;
 margin-top: 9px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 left: 5px;
 border: 1px solid white;
}

.rs {
 height: 145px;
 width: 331px;
 position: relative;
 background-image: url('http://image.prntscr.com/image/6741b6981a9543ac89e23b22521b631b.png');
 display: inline-block;
 background-size: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 14px;
 border: 0.2px solid black;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px black;
 float: right;
}
/* Closing the quest side */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>VainGlory</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='style.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css'>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id = 'structure'>

<!--LS-->

   <div id = 'select'>
    <div id = 'menu1'> <img src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/ddc0c251ac4d4ca6970047e49f575ff4.png'> </div>
    <div class = 'menu'> <img src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/421e8f797e5e4af5abd56e2c84c48884.png'> </div>
    <div class = 'menu'> <img src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/4cb6887febbd4bc7a6f8242688165a9c.png'> </div>
    <div class = 'menu'> <img src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/64bf74940f2449de99f8eedd0115dc55.png'> </div>
    <div class = 'menu'> <img src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/10dd330b566d4b1d9cedc7793c67460b.png'> </div>
    <div class = 'menu'> <img src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/2f4fdfd4a3964536a84689e5316c04e8.png'> </div>
    <div id = 'menu7'> <img src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/ac57c5f7b73f44b8aa92c58a2289cff8.png'> </div>
   </div>

<!--MID-->

   <div id = 'slideImg'>
    <div> <img src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/1025277995cb442a950a05fe3b168614.jpg'> </div>
   </div>

<!--RS-->

   <div id = 'quests'>
    <div class="rs">
     <div id="seasonLevel">
      <div>
       <div>
        <p>10<p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id = 'seasonDesc'>
      <p>Autumn 2016</p>
      <p>Remaining: <span id='time'></span></p>
     </div>
     <div id="sunCont">
      <div class="sun">

      </div>
      <div class="sun">

      </div>
      <div class="sun">

      </div>
      <div class="sun">

      </div>
      <div class="sun">

      </div>
      <div class="sun">

      </div>
      <div class="sun">

      </div>
      <div class="sun">

      </div>
      <div class="sun">

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rs">

    </div>
    <div class="rs">

    </div>
    <div class="rs">
    </div>
   </div>

<!--CLOSE-->

  </div>
  <script src="javas.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look, it looks as though the problem is coming from the border being rendered incorrectly. As far as I know, there's not really a way for a browser to display half a pixel *(ex: 0.2px in the rs class),*

```
.rs {
    height: 145px;
    width: 331px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('http://image.prntscr.com/image/6741b6981a9543ac89e23b22521b631b.png');
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    **border: 0.2px solid black;** <-- This here
}
```

You'll notice that if you add

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

(For testing purposes, what this is doing is making sure that every element in your document displays the border within the element itself rather than bumping out the width of the boxes.)

**EDIT:** If you add this box-sizing style to both the .rs class and the #select id, if should solve the problem. Both of these have borders defined which are bumping your width larger than you initially accounted for.

---

The problem fixes itself and just shows some blue on the right side. (which makes sense since we changed the width of the interior objects)

I think that the reason it is displaying correctly in the 67% zoom is because the 0.5 pixel is being rendered as roughly 1px. The math is a little complicated for me to figure out right away, but if you really want to know - I can look into that!

My suggestion would be to make sure that any of your borders are either whole numbers or by setting your box-sizing on your elements to work as "border-box" rather than the default which adds width to your elements.

Comment: Thank you very much! And also, if you would like and have enough time, would be great to figure how that thing really works.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.rs {
    height: 145px;
    width: 331px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    border: 0.2px solid black;
}
```

This code will do its job!